# Database parameters in properties file not working

Tags: java, sql-server, database-connection, properties-file

Using SQL Server Management Studio, I can log on to a local server, the name is:
**BOB14630\SQL2012** 
(named instance of SQL2012 as I have SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012 on the same machine). 
It logs in fine.

I also have a webapp and am trying to connect to a database called 'Repserv' on that server and am using a properties file to store the config parameters:

If I say:

```
dbConnectString=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://BOB14630/Repserv;instance=SQL2012
```

it gives:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Server BOB14630 has no instance named SQL2012
```

If I say:

```
dbConnectString=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://BOB14630\\SQL2012/Repserv
```

it gives:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown server host name 'BOB14630\SQL2012'
```

What is the correct way to specify these parameters to get the web app to connect?
Thanks.

Comment: See this question, it may be the same exact problem (network configuration of MSSQL) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897075/jdbc-jtds-cant-establish-a-connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link in the comment by Berger above gave the solution (the tcp/ip protocol was disabled). After enabling it and changing the connection string to the following, it worked:

```
dbConnectString=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://BOB14630/Repserv;instance=SQL2012
```